# C++ const member functions are modifying member variables

Tags: c++, function, constants, member

Today I found out that code like that works. That sounds really strange to me, because as far as I always knew you can't modify any of members from const member function. You actually can't do it directly, but you can call non-const member function. if you mark member function as const that means that this pointer passed to the function is pointing to const object, then how non-const member function is called in the example bellow?

```
#include <iostream>

class X
{
public:
    void foo() const
    {
        ptr->bar();
    }
    void bar() {}
private:
    X * ptr;
};

int main()
{
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that changes variables - your code does nothing

Comment: Oops! Sorry :)

This is const pointer and I don't modify the pointer itself, I modify the object under this pointer.

Thanks anyway., this was too long night for my tired brain :)

Comment: I can't see no const here ???

Comment: I can repro this in VS2008. The implementation of foo() should in my understanding not compile because a const member calls a non-const member. I have modified the code to bar modifying a member, and call foo on a const instance of X, no error message. (/W4)

Comment: @peterchen: The compiler is correct. constness is not transitive in that context, that is the X* ptr; will be a X*const ptr, not a X const*const ptr;

Comment: @plasma: That makes sense, but the result is... interesting. http://pastebin.com/BRfkYTSk. calling foo() on a constant instance allows to modify that instance without use of either `mutable` or `const_cast`.  ----  Isn't that another case where a const declaration does not allow the optimizer to draw any conclusions?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176836/how-const-member-function-can-change-an-objects-data

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your member variable is not `X`, but pointer to `X`. As long as `foo` does not modify the pointer, it can be `const`.

Answer (score 5):

When you have a pointer member, then the pointer is const in a const method. You won't be allowed to change the address stored in the pointer. But you can change the pointee all you like.

It's the difference between

```
X* const cannot_change_pointer;  //this is how top-level const applies to pointers
const X* cannot_change_pointee;
```

What's even more interesting is that const on a method has no effect whatsoever on reference members for the same reason (a const method would only prevent you making a reference refer to something else which can't be done with a reference anyway).

Comment: _a const method would only prevent you making a reference refer to something else which can't be done with a reference anyway_ - Amazing observation!

Answer (score 0):

That's seems perfectly OK. The call to foo does not modify the ptr member. Hence, the constness of foo is respected.

my 2 cents

Comment: The fact that bar just happens to do nothing is not significant here.