# How const member function can change an object's data?

Tags: c++, constants

Yet another question about `const` keyword usage in C++ (I am a novice in C++, tried to find an answer on SO - too many answers but failed to find the one).
Question 1: in the following member function

```
template <class T>  
bool BinTree<T>::insert( Node<T>* & node, const T& val ) const  
{
    node = new Node<T>(val);
}
```

I am able to change a class data which is passed as a reference. What about a member function being `const`? Is it true that this `const` prevents data only from changing explicitly, but allows to change it through a reference?
2. Could you confirm my understanding:

```
func( const Node<T>* const & node ) {...}
```

in this function signature the 2-nd `const` means const pointer and the 1-st `const` means const Node (so the node is a reference to const pointer to const Node)?

Comment: The 2-nd confirmed by @tabstop below. What about the first one? I did not post whole code since it's pretty obvious: there is an object's field which is passed as a reference into const member and changed there!

Comment: parashift.com/c++-faq/const-member-fns.html

Comment: "(so the node is a reference to const pointer to const Node)" yes, but the reference aspect is unlikely to have any useful affect, as passing a reference to a `const pointer` likely takes the same number of registers/byte-of-stack as passing the const pointer by value.

Comment: you say in comments that you're passing in the pointer-to-root-node as the "node" parameter when calling "insert": you don't seem to be grocking "encapsulation" or "const"... you generally want to insert data into a tree, where only the tree object itself needs to care which node is the root, i.e. node is a "private" data member.  The `insert` function should then be non-const so it can modify `root`.  As is, your function could be `static` rather than `const`, as it doesn't modify anything based on implicit access to an object instance (i.e. via `this`).

Comment: @Tony D Agreed. As I said in comments, I was playing with const member and expecting an error. To my surprise, no error in this case. The comments below seem to explain this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The member function being const means that, as far as the function is concerned, the `this` object (the `BinTree<T>`) is const.  (And of course `val` is const because it is marked such.)  (Edit: It's a bit surprising, as `insert` doesn't sound like the sort of function you would do to a `const` tree, as you wouldn't be able to update any of the internal data structures.)

Your function signature is correct -- first one means "thing pointed to" is const, second one means pointer itself is const.

---

EDIT based on further discussion in comments:
The function considers the `this` object to be const, and the `node` to be non-const.  As such, you can't change any of the member variables directly. *However*, if `node` happens to be a reference to a member of `this` (say it was called via

```
foo.insert(foo.root);
```

then that *particular* member variable can be changed, but *only through the alias* of `node`.  The compiler is not going to even notice that the two objects `this` and `node` are related, because at the time that it's looking at the function `insert` they're not (only when the call actually happens does the aliasing occur). The `const` only applies to the (literal, if implied) `this`; any other pointers or references hanging around can do what they want.

Comment: You are right about `insert` function, I was just playing, thinking I would get an error for `node = ...` in the const member. So my first question why does it work? Const member function changed a data of `this` .

Comment: I don't know what you mean about "changed a data of `this`".  You changed `node`, which was the argument passed in.  You didn't change anything at all in the `this` object.

Comment: That's the point: I passed the root as a `node` and changed its value. What am I missing?  
Edit: to avoid misunderstanding, I have an BinTree object which has a private field `root` I passed the root into const member function as a reference and successfully changed the `root` value.

Comment: @TT_ It would help if you added that aspect to your question then. But essentially the const only applies to what the compiler can see in the context of that function. It doesn't know where the node parameter came from (after all it could be some other object's Node entirely) so the function-level const doesn't apply to it.

Comment: @TheUndeadFish Actually, this is precisely what I wrote in my first question (omitting only the word `root`). 
Is there any reference: what exactly can't be changed in a const member function? It's confusing.

Comment: Well, it's pretty well described: you can't change any element of `this`.  If some member object of `this` is aliased by a non-constant argument to the function, then that object can be changed, but only through said alias.  (I'd have to break out the standard to see whether we are officially in the land of "undefined"/"unspecified" behavior, but I am not sitting in front of my copy right now.)

Comment: :) Then it's better reformulate: you can't change any element of this, BUT: if some member object is aliased (through a reference for exampe) then you can change an element of this.

Comment: ...then you can change *that particular* element of this, and *only through that alias*.  (For instance, even if you passed in the variable `root` as `node`, you would not have been able to do `root = new whatever`. Any changes must be through the alias, and it is up to the caller of the function to not make a logic error.

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/const-member-fns.html  seems to confirm what you are saying (and I suspected in my question: "... this const prevents data only from changing explicitly, but allows to change it through a reference" ).

Comment: Could you add this to your answer so that I could accept it? (When you have time)