# Const argument of a member function is changed by this function

Tags: c++, arguments, constants

This is an example from "Accelerated C++", 12.3.3. The code is large enough, so I put here only bare minimum. To imitate class string, custom class Str is implemented, which has `vector<char> data`. Operator += is overloaded:

```
Str& operator+=(const Str& s) {
    std::copy(s.data.begin(), s.data.end(), std::back_inserter(data));
    return *this;
}
```

This operator obviously does not work in case `s += s;`, it is compiled successfully but produces garbage (I believe the authors' intention was to get rid of extra details). My question is why it can be compiled - we change data of the `const` argument. I assume this is because we change the data indirectly: compiler can't know the `data` is the same as `s.data`. Could you please confirm? If this is the case, then the issue is very similar to my another question: 
[How const member function can change an object's data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176836/how-const-member-function-can-change-an-objects-data) I just want to be sure.

Comment: The `Str` being changed isn't marked `const` because the function isn't marked `const`. If you make `s` const, it will cause an error as expected. It should work fine as is.

Comment: @chris What do you mean? Is not `const Str& s` marking s as const?

Comment: Yes, but I meant the one where you call `s += s;`. This function does not change its parameter `s` so that's fine, and the function itself isn't marked `const`, so it's free to modify the object, which it does. Anyway, I apologize about it working fine as is, because the iterator invalidation does screw it up.

Comment: @chris Why should you apologize? Let's blame the compiler :) /I'm kidding/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const` references may refer to non-const objects, which is what would happen if you did `s += s;`. The constness in that case only applies to the the object when accessed through that reference. It's the same thing as if you do this:

```
Object non_const_object;
Object const & const_ref = non_const_object;

non_const_object.modify(); // okay
const_ref.modify();        // error, even though it's the same object
```

Comment: So you are confirming my assumption: s.data is const, but compiler does not know it is the same as data.

Comment: @TT_: The compiler may or may not know, but it doesn't matter. It will error if you try to access non-const functions through a const reference to an object, regardless of whether or not it can figure out if that object is actually const.